# Session Modal doesn't appear Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Hi everyone!** I am using Laravel 5.2 for a web application. Within this app, the user can upload files. When the user wants to upload a file, but hasn't selected one they are `Redirect::to` the upload page with the message `status` saying something about choosing a file to upload. The web page used to have this code to show the message:

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Which works great! But due to CSS and JQuery mocking, I would like to have a pop up window with the message. I went to search a few things and I found that a Bootstrap Modal would be the best. I adjusted my code to:

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>{{ session('status') }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

But now, nothing is shown! Could someone help explain to me why the modal isn't visualized?

So I have tried Mayank Pandeyz answer. And then inspected the browser. Which does show that the Modal is called with the right status message!

[image]

Consule error is: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@if (session('status'))
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>{{ session('status') }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $('#myModal').modal('show');    // You have to initialize it as a modal
</script>
@endif
```

Comment: Nope still nothing :-(

Comment: Updated my answer!

Comment: `$ is not defined`

Comment: include the jquery file in your code : https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js and try again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129038/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-anna-jeanine).